Pipeline resource picklist shows failed runs
When running a pipeline with another pipeline as resource you can select the specific run to use in the picklist. By default the last successful should be the selected:

Nevertheless, when you go to the next section (the picklist itself) the selected option by default is the last run (not the last successful run)

Two questions:

Is this any kind of bug or something?
How can I show only the successful runs in the picklist?

PS: Of course I can tag as "successful" all the successful runs and filter by tag the pipeline resource, but tagging as successful something that is visibly "successful" seems a bit redundant... (and besides that, the tag could be removed).

Are you explicitly downloading the artifacts using a task or just defining the pipeline resource?

Hi @RuiJarimba, I want to prevent the pipeline users to select a non-successful run on the picklist

I want to prevent the pipeline users to select a non-successful run - understood. My workaround should probably be used in other scenarios, i.e. non manual builds. If you want users to be able to choose the artifacts then you probably need to add some code to check the status of the associated build and eventually fail it.

But if, on the other hand, you just need to ensure the build uses the latest artifact from a successful build you can use the task I mentioned in my answer.

Not sure if this will help in your particular case, but if you explicitly download an artifact using the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task you can configure whether downloading artifacts from failed or partially succeeded builds is allowed:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    # other properties here
    allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: false # boolean. Optional. Use when source == specific && runVersion != specific. Download artifacts from partially succeeded builds. Default: false.
    allowFailedBuilds: false # boolean. Optional. Use when source == specific && runVersion != specific. Download artifacts from failed builds. Default: false.


Hi @Ruijarimba, I guess this do not change the picklist itself (I mean: the non-successful runs still appear on it). Just curiosity: What if you select on the picklist a non-successful run and you do not allow in the task the Failed/PartiallySucceeded builds, it just break the pipeline?

What if you select on the picklist a non-successful run and you do not allow in the task the Failed/PartiallySucceeded builds, it just break the pipeline? - it depends. For example, a failed build might still generate valid artifact(s) used by the other pipeline but something else fails, like smoke/integration tests.

When you access Resources, currently, it's the default behavior that the first run is selected.
I can reproduce your issue and has found the followings:

If you run the pipeline manually without selecting run manually, the resource actually used is the latest successful run.

If you run the pipeline manually and select one failed run as resource, the selected run will be used.



I understand that you want to prevent the pipeline users to select a non-successful run on the picklist. Currently, there isn't such a feature. If you want, you can submit a feature request to request it from Azure DevOps Developer Community.
As a workaround, you can add a task at the beginning of your triggered pipeline to check whether the resource run is successful using REST API Runs - Get. If it's failed, then fail the current pipeline. Below is a PowerShell script for your reference.
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "{PAT}"
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      $org = "{Your org name}"
      $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$(resources.pipeline.<PipelineResoueceAlias>.projectID)/_apis/pipelines/$(resources.pipeline.<PipelineResoueceAlias>.pipelineID)/runs/$(resources.pipeline.<PipelineResoueceAlias>.runID)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
      $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $head
      
      if ($response.result -eq "succeeded") {
          # If the result is succeeded, run the following steps
          Write-Host "Pipeline run succeeded. Running the following steps..."
          # Add your steps here
      } else {
          # If the result is not succeeded, fail the current pipeline
          Write-Host "Pipeline run did not succeed. Failing the current pipeline..."
          exit 1
      }

In the above scripts, Pipeline resource variables are used to call API.

Update
Currently, it's the default behavior to show all the runs of your resource pipeline in the picklist.
To request filters in the picklist, you can follow this feature request Add filters in Pipeline Resource in the UI.
As mentioned by @Josto, you can add a tag to your successful builds/runs, then use the tag to filter in the picklist.

"If you run the pipeline manually without selecting run manually, the resource actually used is the latest successful run" Okay, this makes sense. Proposed workaround is something that I had thought combined with tagging (successful runs tagged with "successful" tags and filtered)

Hi @Josto, if you just don't want to use a failed resource run, there is no need to use tags. We can check the result of the resource run via the result property in the response body when calling REST API Runs - Get. Besides, the pipeline will only be triggered automatically by the resource pipeline when resource pipeline is successful.

Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, common question among users is: "Why am I seeing failed runs in the picklist if the successful ones (in our work schema) are the only valid? This is confusing" So my main goal is to remove them from the picklist

Currently, it's the default behavior to show all the runs of your resource pipeline in the picklist. Sometimes some users may need a resource pipeline artifact even if it fails. Maybe some tests fail as expected, but the published artifact is still valid, so it needs to appear in the resource picklist. I understand that it is confusing to have both failed and successful runs appearing in the picklist. I have helped you submit a feature request to request a filter based on the run result. You can follow and submit a vote on it, which can be used to increase the priority of the request.

The link to the feature request Add filters in Pipeline Resource in the UI. Hope it's helpful for you. I have also updated it to my answer above to let others who may have the similar request know it more clearly and can follow it. Currently, you can use build tag in the filter as a workaround. And you can also use the PowerShell task above in your pipeline to ensure that your pipeline isn't using a failed run mistakenly.

Thank you for submitting the request @Ziyang Liu-MSFT :)
